Restore a Wordpress Site
I had a wordpress Site that it's down now , I have only wpress file . I want to restore my wordpress site with this file and have not any more files to restore my old site, how can I do it ? I have tried few plugins to restore the site but it showed that the storage is large. now what should I have to do?
